# Ruby on Rails: ActiveStorage only sends first frame of video (Partial Content 206)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activestorage

**Current Behavior:**

Application on navigating to video (/video) only displays the first frame of the video and the console outputs a partial content GET request but doesn't do anything else.

**Code Review:**

```html
<video autoplay=true type="video/mp4" src="<%=@redirectURL%>"/>
```

```rb
class VideoController < ApplicationController
  def index
      ActiveStorage::Current.url_options =  "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
      if session[:user_id]
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @redirectURL = url_for(@user.video)
    end
  end
end
```

```html
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<%= form_with model: @user, url: signup_path do |form|%>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <div> <%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "example@site.com"%>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "secretpassword123" %>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", placeholder: "secretpassword123" %>
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <%= form.label :video, class: "input-group-text", for: "inputGroupFile01"%>
    <%= form.file_field :video, class: "form-control", id: "inputGroupFile01" %>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.submit "Get Started!" , class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--77812323ea618480d0497c73b1b1cb96856a585a/048496124_main_xxl.mp4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-05-04 23:24:24 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::Blobs::RedirectController#show as MP4
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--77812323ea618480d0497c73b1b1cb96856a585a", "filename"=>"048496124_main_xxl"}
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]   
  Disk Storage (1.9ms) Generated URL for file at key: jpgplubo5jtvp1iefb02l82jlfdl (http://127.0.0.1:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhhbkJuY0d4MVltODFhblIyY0RGcFpXWmlNREpzT0RKcWJHWmtiQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVzJGMGRHRmphRzFsYm5RN0lHWnBiR1Z1WVcxbFBTSXdORGcwT1RZeE1qUmZiV0ZwYmw5NGVHd3ViWEEwSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0Snljd05EZzBPVFl4TWpSZmJXRnBibDk0ZUd3dWJYQTBCanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lPZG1sa1pXOHZiWEEwQmpzR1ZEb1JjMlZ5ZG1salpWOXVZVzFsT2dwc2IyTmhiQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0wNVQwMzoyOToyNC4xMzlaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--c56634c4ae269745a756dbc26f32cf373f99b0c9/048496124_main_xxl.mp4)
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhhbkJuY0d4MVltODFhblIyY0RGcFpXWmlNREpzT0RKcWJHWmtiQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVzJGMGRHRmphRzFsYm5RN0lHWnBiR1Z1WVcxbFBTSXdORGcwT1RZeE1qUmZiV0ZwYmw5NGVHd3ViWEEwSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0Snljd05EZzBPVFl4TWpSZmJXRnBibDk0ZUd3dWJYQTBCanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lPZG1sa1pXOHZiWEEwQmpzR1ZEb1JjMlZ5ZG1salpWOXVZVzFsT2dwc2IyTmhiQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0wNVQwMzoyOToyNC4xMzlaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--c56634c4ae269745a756dbc26f32cf373f99b0c9/048496124_main_xxl.mp4
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 2139)
```

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhhbkJuY0d4MVltODFhblIyY0RGcFpXWmlNREpzT0RKcWJHWmtiQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpVzJGMGRHRmphRzFsYm5RN0lHWnBiR1Z1WVcxbFBTSXdORGcwT1RZeE1qUmZiV0ZwYmw5NGVHd3ViWEEwSWpzZ1ptbHNaVzVoYldVcVBWVlVSaTA0Snljd05EZzBPVFl4TWpSZmJXRnBibDk0ZUd3dWJYQTBCanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lPZG1sa1pXOHZiWEEwQmpzR1ZEb1JjMlZ5ZG1salpWOXVZVzFsT2dwc2IyTmhiQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0wNVQwMzoyOToyNC4xMzlaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--c56634c4ae269745a756dbc26f32cf373f99b0c9/048496124_main_xxl.mp4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-05-04 23:24:24 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as MP4
  Parameters: {"encoded_key"=>"[FILTERED]", "filename"=>"048496124_main_xxl"}
Completed 206 Partial Content in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 279)
```

**Expected Behavior:**

The current application allows a user to signup (/signup), submit email, password, password confirmation, and video file during signup. When the user navigates to video (/video) it should display the video and start playing via video tag.

**What I Have Tried / Confirmed:**

- Video.js (Same behavior)
- Restarting the Server
- Confirmed user.video has a video object (*ActiveStorage::Attached::One*)
- Tried different videos uploaded (*2GB and 1MB respectfully*)
- Confirmed vide source in browser developer tools

```html
<video autoplay="true" type="video/mp4" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--77812323ea618480d0497c73b1b1cb96856a585a/048496124_main_xxl.mp4</video>
```